# Склонять ли Васко да Гам(у)/(а)?

Tags: склонение, ономастика

Склонять ли Васко да Гаму?.. Думаю, что надо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я тоже думаю, что склонять надо.

Есть источники с пометкой ***нескл.***, например [academic.ru](https://orthographic.academic.ru/4498/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0) со ссылкой на Орфографический словарь русского языка. А вот Словарь имён собственных склоняет: **ГАМА Васко да,** Гамы Васко да ([Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)).

*Отцом Васко да Гам**ы** был Эстеван да Гама...* ([Википедия](https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.cc7820d5-62c73486-5971da27-74722d776562/https/en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasco_da_Gama)).

А это из занятной, даже юморной статейки «Фамилии склоняемые и несклоняемые» ([LIVEJOURNAL](https://sergedid.livejournal.com/87109.html)):

> Правильно: *морской путь в Индию, открытый Васко да Гам**ой**!* (А не «открытый Васко да Гама».)

**Правило** с Грамоты.ру: [**Как склонять фамилии (трудные случаи)**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/71)

> Все фамилии, кончающиеся на **неударное *а* после согласных**, склоняются по первому склонению: *Рибера — Риберы, Рибере, Риберу, Риберой, Сенека — Сенеки* и т. д.; так же склоняются *Кафка, Спиноза, Сметана, Петрарка, Куросава, Глинка, Дейнека, Гулыга, Олеша, Нагнибеда, Окуджава* и др. Все такие фамилии, независимо от происхождения, являются морфологически членимыми в русском языке, т. е. в них выделяется окончание *-а*.

В Нацкорпусе много **примеров со склонением:**

*Построена в 1515 – 1521 годах Франсишку де Аррудой в честь открытия Васко да Гам**ой** морского пути в Индию.* [Роман Романов. Вom caminho, или Пилигримуши на Пути Святого Иакова // «Дальний Восток», 2019]

*И я увлеченно прокладывал на карте пути Колумба и Магеллана, капитана Кука и Васко да Гам**ы***. [Борис Васильев. Оглянись на середине // «Октябрь», 2003]

*А он нам ― о Васко да Гам**е***. [Александр Городницкий. «И жить еще надежде» (2001)]

*Но однажды, слушая рассказы Васко да Гам**ы** об Индии, не поверил тому и написал ставший знаменитым трактат «Похвальное слово Глупости».* [Геннадий Брониславский. ЖЗЛ. Факты, события, мнения // «Родник», 1989]

*...два года спустя после знаменитого путешествия Васко да Гам**ы***... [Г. Малиничев. А был ли бразильский камень? // «Техника - молодежи», 1974]

*Когда один из индийских князей спросил Васко да Гам**у**, что привело его в Индию, тот ответил: «Желание распространить христианство и получить пряности».* [М. Черников. Север и юг: контрасты питания // «Химия и жизнь», 1969]

Answer (score 0):

В русском склоняется всё, особенность языка такая, которой в португальском уже нет. Отсюда все эти казусы с любыми заимствованными словами, которые в оригинале не предполагают склонений, что особенно забавно в свете множественного числа. Классический пример - арабское "наваб", множественное (или двойственное) от "наиб", которое в русском превращается в "навабы". Впрочем, это норма не только у нас.